# JQuery diff two dates

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have jQuery code here which computing the sum of two dates. Now, I want to separate the answer (days) into three fields: Year, Month, Days.

```
<i> Example: the answer is Days: 400 </i>
```

**Output that I want is**

> Year: *1*  Month: *1*    Days:  *5*

Below is my code:

```
<p>Date 1: <input name="datepickerln1" id="datepickerln1" type="text" /></p>
<p>Date 2:<input name="datepickerln2" id="datepickerln2" type="text" /> </p>
days: <input name="total" id="total" type="text" readonly /><br/>
month: <input name="mtotal" id="mtotal" type="text" readonly /><br/>
year: <input name="ytotal" id="ytotal" type="text" readonly />
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var selector = function (dateStr) {
        var d1 = $('#datepickerln1').datepicker('getDate');
        var d2 = $('#datepickerln2').datepicker('getDate');
        var diff = 0;
        if (d1 && d2) {
            diff = Math.floor((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / 86400000); // ms per day
        }
        $('#total').val(diff);
    }
    $("#datepickerln1").datepicker();
    $('#datepickerln2').datepicker();
    $('#datepickerln1,#datepickerln2').change(selector)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/433d9/26/

Comment: you should use momentjs - it gives you pretty much exactly what you want.

Comment: i don't know how to use that sir. can you teach me? or give me example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick and dirty way is to make a new `Date` based on the difference and then pull the year, month, and day from that (well... `1970 - year` because 1970 is the year for `new Date(0)`).

As applied to your `selector` function:

```
var selector = function (dateStr) {
    var d1 = $('#datepickerln1').datepicker('getDate'),
        d2 = $('#datepickerln2').datepicker('getDate'),
        diff = 0,
        d = 0,
        m = 0,
        y = 0;
    if (d1 && d2) {
        diff = new Date(d2.getTime() - d1.getTime());
        d = diff.getUTCDate() - 1;
        m = diff.getUTCMonth();
        y = Math.abs(1970 - diff.getUTCFullYear());
    }
    $('#total').val(d);
    $('#mtotal').val(m);
    $('#ytotal').val(y);
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/433d9/28/

You could use another library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for this, but what you want is pretty simple so I wouldn't bother with the added overhead. If you want to use the moment.js library for this, your selector function would look more like this:

```
var selector = function (dateStr) {
    var d1 = $('#datepickerln1').datepicker('getDate'),
        d2 = $('#datepickerln2').datepicker('getDate');
    if (d1 && d2) {
        d1 = moment(d1);
        d2 = moment(d2);
    }
    $('#total').val(d1.from(d2));
}
```

This will give results like:

> About a month ago

If you specifically need an exact breakdown of years, months, and days, then I definitely wouldn't use moment.js for this. While it can be done with moment.js, it would require significantly more code to accomplish.

Comment: Sir Pete. thank you very much. but why the result of the year is negtive(-1)?

Comment: @kentyo: Because I neglected to account for the future case. :) Sorry about that. Updated answer and fiddle.

Comment: Sir thank you very much. thank you. this is very helpful in my thesis system. Thank you very much sir. ! More power!